# Django + RabbitMQ multiple Tabs

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pika

In my project, I'm using pika/RabbitMQ to send a SQL script from my web page to a remote database. This database processes and returns the conclusion. My problem is that I want to give my users the possibility to use multiple tabs to connect to different databases simultaneously to expedite remote maintenance.

However, I'm facing a significant challenge when attempting to use Django's local storage and session storage. Since each tab shares the same session, changing the session affects everyone. I'm using a control inside my consumer to manage Rabbit consumers individually and to stop only the one that received a response, or to force a consumer to stop if the user refreshes the page. I'm open to any suggestions for a solution. Should I use websockets? Try generating an ID on the client side for control? Any other good solutions?

This is my consumer code:

```
import pika
from comandos.connectionAMQP.connectionSettings import getConnectionRabbitMQ

class MessageReturn:
    def __init__(self, consumer_key) -> None:
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.message_body = None
        self.is_consuming = True

    def set_message_body(self, body):
        self.message_body = body

    def get_message_body(self):
        return self.message_body

    def stop_consuming(self):
        self.is_consuming = False

# Lista para armazenar instâncias de MessageReturn
consumers = []

def create_consumer(consumer_key):
    global consumers
    consumer = MessageReturn(consumer_key)
    consumers.append(consumer)
    return consumer

def stop_consume(consumer_key):
    global consumers
    for consumer in consumers:
        if consumer.consumer_key == consumer_key and consumer.is_consuming:
            consumer.stop_consuming()
            print(f"Consumption stopped for consumer {consumer_key}.")
            break
    else:
        print(f"No active consumption to stop for consumer {consumer_key}.")

def consume(consumer_key):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(getConnectionRabbitMQ())
    channel = connection.channel()

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        for consumer in consumers:
            if consumer.consumer_key == consumer_key:
                consumer.set_message_body(body.decode('utf-8'))
                consumer.stop_consuming()

    global consumers
    state = create_consumer(consumer_key)

    channel.basic_consume(queue='Response_BKP_00788556-af71-4c99-a8c8-1fde8841e1ae', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    print(f'[*] Waiting for messages for consumer {consumer_key}. To exit press CTRL+C')

    while state.is_consuming:
        connection.process_data_events()

    connection.close()
    return state.get_message_body()
```

I call my consumer with a generated UUID for control, and use this unique ID to enforce a stop if the user refreshes the page. However, I'm facing difficulties with using local storage, as it keeps replacing my UUID.

I'm a desktop developer, so web dev is new to me and I'm using Django for the first time, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: If you have a web app open in several tabs and you want each to have its own session, you could redirect the URL in each to generate a UUID. Each tab would then have its own token that you can use to independently store state within the shared session.

Comment: Like /page/uuid? In my code of the consumer, is better to encapsulate on a class and create the object in my view request? Because I tested in multiple devices and, with this code, when I call stop_consume it stops all the consumer. I think that my code is kind of shared with all the acesses

Comment: "Like /page/uuid?" - yep. Give it a try. I assume sessions in Django are a dictionary, so you can do `session[varname1_uuid]` and `session[varname2_uuid]` (pseudocode) to keep the values tab-specific.